# lupdate error: Qualifying with unknown namespace/class

Tags: qt, internationalization, namespaces, translation

I ran into a very peculiar error using lupdate v4.7.2. I got the error message

> module/foo.cpp:6: Qualifying with unknown namespace/class ::foo

for a couple of classes in a project with about 50 classes. I boiled the problem down to a simple example:

src/project.pro:

```
QT       += core
TARGET = test
TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp \
           screen.cpp

HEADERS += screen.h

TRANSLATIONS += de.ts
```

src/module/foo.h:

```
namespace sp {
class foo {
    initWidgets();
};
} // namespace sp
```

src/module/foo.cpp:

```
#include <QString>
#include "module/foo.h"

namespace sp {
    foo::initWidgets() {
    QString bar = tr("bar");
}
} // namespace sp
```

main.cpp has an empty main function in it.

The code compiles (barring any copypasta mistakes I might have produced here), so the syntax is basically correct.

Comment: You're missing a return type for `initWidgets();`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer was that lupdate was unable to locate the header file foo.h while parsing foo.cpp. Extending the .pro file with the following line removed the issue:

```
INCLUDEPATH += .
```

However, what still bothers me a bit is that the compiler should have been unable to compile the code, but somehow, qmake added a `-I.` to the compiler options. That's why I didn't think of an include file issue earlier and spent a couple of hours puzzling this out. Does anyone know whether this is default behavior? Also: Why does lupdate not emit an appropriate error message?

Comment: I had the same problem, your solution did not work for me straight away but pointed me in the right direction. According to [this](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-24587?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel) bug report, the root of the problem is that lupdate searches for include files relative to the current directory. In my case, I had to add `INCLUDEPATH += ../src`, because the current directory was `./translations`.

Comment: @Wutz thanks.  Your comment further  helped me solve the build error.

Answer (score 4):

In my case lupdate wasn't able to parse enum MyEnum:int {}; line and failed to reach class declaration. Qt 5.7.1, lupdate still does not understand type specifiers for enums.

Comment: This was the issue for me. Quite annoying. Did you find a workaround?

Answer (score 2):

I have seen this error message too using Qt 5.4.1 on an Ubuntu 12.04 system.

But the reason for the error was different. "lupdate" seems to have problems with C++-11 strong enums, at least when using related forward declarations encapsulated in a namespace.

I'm using something like this in the related header file:

```
namespace outer {
namespace other {
  enum class MyEnum : int;
} // namespace outer::other

namespace inner {
   class MyClass {
     //...
   };
} // namespace outer::inner
} // namespace outer
```

The problem with "lupdate" can be worked around by using a marco for the term "enum class":

```
#ifndef ENUM_CLASS
#define ENUM_CLASS enum class
#endif

namespace outer {
namespace other {
  ENUM_CLASS MyEnum : int;
} // namespace outer::other

namespace inner {
   class MyClass {
     //...
   };
} // namespace outer::inner
} // namespace outer
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case there was a strangely (but legally I guess) formatted type declaration in a struct before the actual class declaration.  This made `lupdate` skip the class and resulted in the "unqualified" warning message.  The code looked like this (wasn't mine to begin with ;-) ):

```
struct coords_t {
  double x, y;
  ...
};

struct plotsCollection {
  QVarLengthArray<struct coords_t> coords;  // problem right here
  ...
};

class LogsDialog : public QDialog
{
  Q_OBJECT
  ...
}
```

Removing the `struct` from `QVarLengthArray<struct coords_t>` solved the warning.  So did moving the struct declarations inside the class.  I did both  :)

Answer (score 1):

I just got this same message in a different scenario. In my case, the issue was that `foo.cpp` contained `#include <foo.h>` instead `#include "foo.h"`. Since both files were a directory that wasn't in the global include path, `lupdate` didn't bother looking in that directory due to the lack of quotation marks in the include. Switching to the proper include delimiters made `lupdate` happy.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs also if the `tr()`-macro is placed in too deeply nested subfolders.

E.g., in the following example, the command
`lupdate -noobsolete . -ts ts/*`
error message reads
`pwd/a/b/c/c.cpp:5: Qualifying with unknown namespace/class ::C`.

```
QT       += core gui

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    a/a.cpp \
    a/b/b.cpp \
    a/b/c/c.cpp

HEADERS += \
    a/a.h \
    a/b/b.h \
    a/b/c/c.h

TRANSLATIONS += \
    ts/foo.ts
```

However, as others have already mentioned, the `*.ts`-file seems to be updated correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Some forward declarations seem to cause this warning too.
Removing the 'template  class MutexQList' line in this class example solves the issue in my case:

```
#include "bufferwriter.h"
#include "resampleworker.h"
#include "worker_help.h"

class Buffer;
class Project;

template <class T> class MutexQList;

class WorkerRegistry : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    static WorkerRegistry *my_instance;

    MutexQList<BufferWriter *>*bw_list;                 ///< Liste mit registrierten BufferWriter Instanzen
    MutexQList<ResampleWorker *>*rw_list;               ///< Liste mit registrierten ResampleWorker Instanzen

public:
    static WorkerRegistry *instance();
    static WorkerRegistry &ref();
    static void destroy();
}
```